# Always compile with utf8 encoding

Tags: java, encoding

I search a solution to always compile a java source file with utf8 encoding option.
I'ts boring to type `javac -encoding utf8 Source.java`
Is there a solution to compile in utf8 by default?

Thanks.

Comment: why use utf8 encoding anyway?

Comment: @tbodt Because I'm french and special characters like 'é' or 'à' aren't supported so I have to compile with utf8 encoding

Comment: I try to keep my sources strictly ASCII. It is much less sensitive to encoding this way. Even more important if the source is processed on different machines.

Comment: what operating system do you use?

Comment: Use an [IDE](http://netbeans.org/). That will take care of all your problems for you.

Comment: @MathieuBrochard there are unicode escapes `\uxxxx`. Not nice to type but should appear only in strings which should go to a property file anyhow. Java identifiers can always be in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable to `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`

Comment: If this works (and the doc is a bit unclear) it's a fine solution.